# Añadir dos funciones distintas al mismo botón C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Estoy simulando con 10 botones los asientos de un teatro, y cuando pulsas uno de ellos se cambia el color a **amarillo**, indicando en este caso que lo has reservado.

Pero si se vuelve a pulsar se queda en amarillo, y me gustaría que alternara el color de verde-amarillo y amarillo-verde con cada `click`. Es decir, puedo reservar un asiento, o anular la reserva.

```
    private void bt1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var botonP = ((Button)sender); //Capturo el boton

        foreach (var i in asientos)
        {
            if(botonP.Content.ToString() == i.Columna.ToString())
            {
                i.Estado = "Reservado";
                asientosVerdes = false;
                botonP.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 107)); //Cambiamos color a: Amarillo. 
            }
        }           
    }
```

Ese es el método que controla dichos botones, tengo una lista de 10 asientos, y el atributo `columna` va desde el 1 al 10 y por eso lo comparo en el `if`, para que aparte de cambiarle el color, necesito modificar el atributo `estado`.

Asi esta la lista de asientos:

```
asientos.Add(new Asiento(1, 1, "libre"));
```

**EDITO:**

La clase Asiento es esta:

```
public class Asiento
{
    public Asiento()
    {
    }

    public Asiento(int fila, int columna, string estado)
    {
        this.Fila = fila;
        this.Columna = columna;
        this.Estado = estado;
    }

    public int Fila { get; set; }
    public int Columna { get; set; }
    public string Estado { get; set; }
}
```

Y la variable `asientosVerdes` la utilizo como `boolean`, por si el usuario **no selecciona ninguna butaca**, le salte un mensaje indicándolo. Simplemente es por avisar al usuario.

Comment: Hola, indica por favor la clase `Asiento` y que es la variable `asientosVerdes`.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar tu propiedad Estado

```
if (i.Estado != "Reservado")
{
    i.Estado = "Reservado";
    asientosVerdes = false;
    botonP.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 107));
}
else
{
    i.Estado = "Libre";
    asientosVerdes = true;
    botonP.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(34, 177, 76));
}
```

Y en vez de la variable asientosVerdes te sugiero revises si no existe ni un asiento reservado cuando el usuario intente confirmar, así puedes eliminar esa variable extra, por ejemplo

```
if (asientos.Count(a => a.Estado == "Reservado") == 0)
{
   Console.Log("No ha reservado ningún asiento.");
 }
```